# How would I use mailto to send a formatted email to someone, containing data pulled from the webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

So lets say I have a questionaire that has textareas, text boxes, and check/radio buttons, and I want the user to fill out the questionaire and when they're finished, be able to click the submit button to bring up and email to send to me with a format that is easy to read like this:

```
Question A: [value of question a]
Question B: [value of question b]
etc...
```

I'm not sure whether this would be capable using javascript or HTML, so I'll tag as both. I've been looking around but have been unable to find anything that can tell me how to do so.

Comment: I've tried a simple mailto as well as a &body message, but I have no clue how I'm supposed to get input from textareas as using '+document.getElementById('q1resp').value+' after a &body= doesn't give me anything.

Comment: Start showing some code and what you have tried. Btw Google is a good start for such a basic question

Comment: I've been googling for the past 2 hours. Virtually none of the sites are any use and the ones I have tried have not given me what I wanted. I can format, kinda, but have absolutely no idea how to pull data and put it into the body text.

Comment: You are looking for a very old technique. Form action="mailto can be a good start. But it will open user's mail program to send you an email. Btw it's html

Comment: action="mailto is what I originally used, until I realized that the format in which it placed the data was extremely lackluster and didn't include textareas, only input text.

Comment: No guess on what's included or not without looking at the code. But for the format better if you process your form with something like php and then use it's mail function to send a formatted email.

Comment: If you have PHP available to you, try to make an invisible iframe, that sends the results via POST to a PHP file. That PHP file can then send you an email on its own, and the user experience in uninterrupted by email clients opening on the client-side.